# Arithmetic and geometric average error solution

Tags: c, c99

My code causes problems connected with giving the final result. 
Earlier the program returned that there is an error in division by zero in geometric average. Now the program in arithmetic average returns -2.00000.
Program shows #IND00 error in `SredniaGeometryczna();` — it is Geometric Average.

Do you have any idea how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int ilosc(int*);
double sredniaArytmetyczna(int, int*); 
double sredniaGeometryczna(int, int*);
double sredniaHarmoniczna(int, int*);

int main()
{
    int tab[10];

    char wybor;
    printf("Wybierz, ktora srednia chcesz policzyc: [A]rytmetyczna, [G]eometryczna, [H]armoniczna.\n");
    wybor=getch();
    int ile;
    long double srednia;
    switch(wybor)
    {
    case 'a':
    case 'A':
        //instrukcje dla arytmetycznej
        ile=ilosc(tab);
        srednia=sredniaArytmetyczna(ile, tab);
        printf("Srednia to: %f",srednia);
        //tab* == tab[0]
        //printf("Srednia to: %f", sredniaArytmetyczna(ilosc(tab),tab)); - mozna tak samo zrobic za pomoca jednej linijki

        break;
    case 'g':
    case 'G':
        //instrukcje dla geometrycznej
        ile=ilosc(tab);
        srednia=sredniaGeometryczna(ile, tab);
        printf("Srednia to: %f",srednia);

        break;
    case 'h':
    case 'H':
        ile=ilosc(tab);
        srednia=sredniaHarmoniczna(ile, tab);
        printf("Srednia to: %f",srednia);
        break;


    default:
        printf("Bledny wybor");
    }

    return 0;
}

int ilosc(int* tablica)  
{
    int ileLiczb, i;
    printf("Podaj ile liczb chcesz wprowadzic (max 10) : \n");

    scanf("%d", &ileLiczb);
    i=0;
    while(i<ileLiczb)
    {
        printf("Podaj %d liczbe calkowita: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &tablica[i]);
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}

double sredniaArytmetyczna(int iloscLiczb, int *Tab)
{
    double wynik=0;

    for(int i=0; i<iloscLiczb; ++i)
    {
        wynik+=Tab[i];
    }

    return wynik/iloscLiczb;
}

double sredniaGeometryczna(int iloscLiczb, int *Tab)
{

    double wynik=0;

    for(int i=0; i<iloscLiczb; ++i)
    {
        wynik=Tab[i]*Tab[++i];
    }

    return pow(wynik,1/iloscLiczb);
}

double sredniaHarmoniczna(int iloscLiczb, int *Tab)
{

    double wynik=0;

    for(int i=0; i<iloscLiczb; ++i)
    {
        wynik+=(1/Tab[i]);
    }

    return iloscLiczb/wynik;
}
```

Comment: Hello Mouse! To make things easier, you may want to refactor your code and translate all variables and function names to english.

Comment: @Barthy: think of it as an oddball naming convention imposed by corporate standards.  It is comprehensible as it is.

Comment: Hello @Barthy, here is some translation:

ileLiczb - amount of numbers
tablica - array of numbers

sredniaArytmetyczna() - Arithmetic Average
wynik - adding to variable

pow - power

sredniaHarmoniczna() -  Harmonic Avarage
 
Is it enough ? :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler of course it is. I said to make things easier, not that it was impossible ;)

Comment: @Mouse thank you for answering to my comment! You could also have edited your question and translated all the things. Remember that for the next question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ilosc` is supposed to return the count of numbers, but it always returns `0`. Change

```
return 0;
```

to

```
return ileLiczb;
```

And when you're calculating the power in `sredniaGeometryczna`, you're performing integer arithmetic. You need to change `1/iloscLiczb` to `1/(double)iloscLiczb` so it will perform floating point arithmetic. Or you could change the declaration of the `iloscLiczb` parameter to `double`, and it will be converted automatically when the function is called.

You need a similar change in `sredniaHarmoniczna`. Change `1/Tab[i]` to `1/(double)Tab[i]`